# Wired connection not working in Network Manager

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, wired, lshw

On my desktop running Kubuntu 20.04, my wired connection recently stopped working. I searched, but found no solution. I tried deleting and re-adding a network connection, but to no avail:
Network manager GUI screenshot
[image]
Here are some additional information about my Network manager:

```
raphael@raphael-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2204000-f2204fff memory:f2200000-f2203fff

raphael@raphael-desktop:~$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

raphael@raphael-desktop:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
total 4
-rw------- 1 root root 286 Jan 14 23:28 'New 802-3-ethernet connection.nmconnection'
```

The logs from network manager also don't have any big error, here are the last lines:

```
raphael@raphael-desktop:~$ sudo tail -n 1500 /var/log/syslog | grep Network
[...]
NetworkManager[741]: <warn>  [1610664805.5023] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
NetworkManager[741]: <info>  [1610664805.5168] manager: startup complete
systemd[1]: Finished Network Manager Wait Online.
systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
NetworkManager[741]: <info>  [1610664805.5415] modem-manager: ModemManager not available
NetworkManager[741]: <info>  [1610664805.5731] modem-manager: ModemManager now available
NetworkManager[741]: <info>  [1610664815.1515] agent-manager: agent[27338341a6c7b457,:1.43/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered
systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
```

Finally, I tested the ethernet cable on another machine and it was working perfectly well.
What should I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: here are more requested information:

```
raphael@raphael-desktop:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
```

and

```
raphael@raphael-desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                     2.34-6ubuntu1                               amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                           1.194ubuntu3                                all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                             3.0-1build2                                 amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                                1.18.0-2build1                              amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                          1.18.0-2build1                              amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu3.1                                all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                1.187.2                                     all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                                 5.4.0.62.65                                 amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-42                        5.4.0-42.46                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-62                        5.4.0-62.70                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-62-generic                5.4.0-62.70                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                         5.4.0.62.65                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic                  5.4.0-42.46                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-62-generic                  5.4.0-62.70                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-38-generic                  5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           5.4.0.62.65                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          5.4.0-62.70                                 amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-62-generic                5.4.0-62.70                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-38-generic                5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic          5.4.0-42.46                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-62-generic          5.4.0-62.70                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-42-generic     5.4.0-42.46                                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-42
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-440-generic-hwe-20.04    5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1                         amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-440 for the generic flavour (dummy trans
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.8.0-38-generic     5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-38
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04    5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1                         amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-450 for generic-hwe-20.04
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                        all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                    1.10.0-1build1                              amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                      3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2         amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                               3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2         all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                               2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                        amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                    2.34-0.1ubuntu9                             amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

Comment: Recently like right after an update?

Comment: exactly, you are right

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: And also `dpkg -l | grep linux`

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the reply, I have added the output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel is not installed properly. `linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-38-generic` is missing.

Connect to the internet using some other way, or boot with the `5.4` kernel.

Then run

```
 sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-38-generic
```

Comment: It worked. I also had to install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-38-generic and it was fixed. Thanks